# Group DF by hour of day

Tags: apache-spark

I've read a bunch of threads, but I can't find what I'm looking for in Apache Spark (though I've found it in PySpark, which I cannot use). I'm pretty close with what I have, but I have a few questions.

I'm working off a DF that looks like the following

| PULocationID | pickup_datetime | number_of_pickups | Borough | Zone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 75 | 2019-01-19 02:13:00 | 5 | Brooklyn | Williamsburg |
| 255 | 2019-01-19 12:05:00 | 8 | Brooklyn | Williamsburg |
| 99 | 2019-01-20 12:05:00 | 3 | Brooklyn | DUMBO |
| 102 | 2019-01-01 02:05:00 | 1 | Brooklyn | DUBMO |
| 10 | 2019-01-07 11:05:00 | 13 | Brooklyn | Park Slope |
| 75 | 2019-01-01 11:05:00 | 2 | Brooklyn | Williamsburg |
| 12 | 2019-01-11 01:05:00 | 1 | Brooklyn | Park Slope |
| 98 | 2019-01-28 01:05:00 | 8 | Brooklyn | DUMBO |
| 75 | 2019-01-10 00:05:00 | 8 | Brooklyn | Williamsburg |
| 255 | 2019-01-11 12:05:00 | 12 | Brooklyn | DUMBO |

I need to pull the zone with the highest number of pickups by hour of day. Hour of Day needs to be an integer, zone a string, and max_count integer.

| hour_of_day | zone | max_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Williamsburg | 8 |
| 1 | DUMBO | 8 |
| 2 | Williamsburg | 5 |
| 11 | Park Slope | 13 |
| 12 | DUMBO | 15 |

Here's what I had:

```
val groupByWindow = BK_joined.groupBy(window(col("pickup_datetime"), "1 hour").as("hour_of_day"))
.agg(max("number_of_pickups").as("max_count")).select("hour_of_day", "Zone", "max_count")
```

There are two problems with this:

- This breaks down each day by hour, not the hour across all days
- I get an error "cannot resolve '`Zone`' given input columns: [hour_of_day, max_count]"

I tried making a table that was already grouped by zone and time, but I don't think that would give me the right solution...

```
val groupByWindow = BK_joined.groupBy("Zone", "pickup_datetime")
.agg(max("number_of_pickups").as("max_count")).select("pickup_datetime", "Zone", "max_count")
```

Even if this is right, I still can't figure out how to get the timestamp grouped by hour of day. I tried various versions of the below:

```
val windowed = groupByWindow.groupBy(window(col("pickup_datetime"), "1 hour").as("hour_of_day"))
```

Comment: Can you please add few more rows say 10 minimum ? and your expected result. Thanks

Comment: Just added some more data and a sample of the results. The full result table would have hours 0-23. It should look at all pickups for every hour of the day in every zone in Brooklyn and return the highest (i.e. max() ) number of pickups and the corresponding for each hour. E.g. in the above: 3 zones have pickups at 12 PM, but DUMBO has the highest number of pickups, it is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is convert the string type to timestamp type and use SQL function to extract hour and then use Window spec with row_number(), finally filter row number 1.

Check the online code version @ https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/8963851468310921/992546394267440/5846184720595634/latest.html

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq(                                                                
(75,  "2019-01-19 02:13:00",  5 ,   "Brooklyn", "Williamsburg"),        
(255, "2019-01-19 12:05:00",  8 ,   "Brooklyn", "Williamsburg"),        
(99,  "2019-01-20 12:05:00",  3 ,   "Brooklyn", "DUMBO"),               
(102, "2019-01-01 02:05:00",  1 ,   "Brooklyn", "DUBMO"),               
(10,  "2019-01-07 11:05:00",  13,   "Brooklyn", "Park Slope"),          
(75,  "2019-01-01 11:05:00",  2 ,   "Brooklyn", "Williamsburg"),        
(12,  "2019-01-11 01:05:00",  1 ,   "Brooklyn", "Park Slope"),          
(98,  "2019-01-28 01:05:00",  8 ,   "Brooklyn", "DUMBO"),               
(75,  "2019-01-10 00:05:00",  8 ,   "Brooklyn", "Williamsburg"),        
(255, "2019-01-11 12:05:00",  12,   "Brooklyn", "DUMBO"),               
).toDF("PULocationID", "pickup_datetime", "number_of_pickups", "Borough", "Zone")
df.show()

val df1 = df.
            withColumn("pickup_datetime", F.to_timestamp(F.col("pickup_datetime"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).
            withColumn("hour", F.hour(F.col("pickup_datetime")))
df1.show()
df1.printSchema()

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("hour").orderBy(F.desc("number_of_pickups"))
val df2 = df1.withColumn("rn", F.row_number.over(windowSpec))

df2.filter(F.col("rn") === 1).drop(F.col("rn")).select("hour", "Zone", "number_of_pickups").show()
```